# How to delete a tkinter-tooltip?

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip

Let say you have created a tkinter-tooltip using below package.
(... for an app that has two buttons, one to select directory and one to execute a program. You want the user to understand that the directory must be selected prior to running the script.)

[image]

```
from tktooltip import ToolTip
from tkinter import ttk

self.button_explore = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text = "Select a directory",command= self.browse_files)
self.button_run = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text = "Execute the program", 
                                state='disabled', command= self.run_main)
self.tt = ToolTip(self.button_run, msg="Select a directory beforehand.", delay=0.5)

self.button_explore.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
self.button_run.grid(column = 2,row = 2)
```

Good! The user has selected the directory. Now, how to delete the Tooltip?

The `self.tt.destroy()` method seems to make trouble. While the forget method does not do anything.

pypi page: [tkinter-tooltip](https://pypi.org/project/tkinter-tooltip/)

Comment: Can you explain the problem with `.destroy()`? Also the tooltip is its own window so `.pack_forget`/`.grid_forget`/`.place_forget` aren't going to do anything.

Comment: @TheLizzard when doing destroy I get ```tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!tooltip2"``` each time I hover the button

Comment: Why not use `self.tt.delay = 100000`? I looked at the `Toolbar`'s code and there is no method for removing it and it doesn't keep a reference to it's bindings. Therefore, why not increase the delay to a very large number, that will make it practically invisible.

Comment: I filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/gnikit/tkinter-tooltip/issues/39). So it might get solved (probably not).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved by the following.

In my case I have a data-grid class instantiated (bunch of tkinter labels) on a tkinter window.  Inside the class I added an array element to store the each created tool-tip.

self.tt = ToolTip(self.class_label, msg="some_value")
self.tooltips.append(self.tt)

Later in your code you can update the msg to whatever you want by referring to the index of the array.

self.tooltips[idx].msg = "some_new_value"

Comment: OP is looking to remove a tooltip. So, should they set the indexed object to None as the appropriate time?

Comment: I tried that but it failed stating bad window path.  I also tried setting the object index's msg to "" but it came up as a small block of background which wasn't going to fly either.  Probably it's best he submitted a ticket to see if the destroy or forget methods get fixed.

Comment: Had another case where I needed to modify instead of solely delete, your answer's great in that case. Used it in a simpler way than using a tooltip list though

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of `tktooltip`, you need to remove the binding of events added by `ToolTip()` on the button if you want to disable the tooltip.

I assume you want to disable the tooltip inside `self.browse_files()`:

```py
def browse_files(self):
    # do whatever you want
    ...
    # remove the event bindings on self.button_run
    for event in self.button_run.bind():
        self.button_run.bind(event, "")
    # destroy the tooltip window
    self.tt.destroy()
    # enable the button_run
    self.button_run.config(state="normal")
```

Comment: When using destroy, I keep having this error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!tooltip5"`.